# Text Pivot Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example of the data I am working with:

```
     TABLE 1                 TABLE 2                        TABLE 3
PK   | Col   | Status |   | PK | FK  |       | PK  |  FK   | Description|  Value
-----------------------   ------------       ----------------------------------------
123  | Data  | Active |   |456 | 123 |       | 301 | 456   |  Status    |  Abandoned
                          |789 | 123 |       | 302 | 456   |  Material  |  Steel
                          |012 | 123 |       | 303 | 456   |  Feet      |  10
                                             | 304 | 789   |  Status    |  Installed
                                             | 305 | 789   |  Material  |  Plastic 
                                             | 306 | 789   |  Feet      |  15
                                             | 307 | 012   |  Status    |  Removed 
                                             | 308 | 012   |  Material  |  Steel
                                             | 309 | 012   |  Feet      |  5
```

I need to return:

```
t1.PK  | t1.Col  |  t3.Status    |   t3.Material  |  t3.Feet
-------------------------------------------------------------
123    | Value   | Abandoned     |   Steel        |  10
```

The issue I have is with the aggregating functions required for PIVOT. The query I've written is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT t1.PK, t1.Col, t3.Description, t3.Value
 FROM table1 t1 
 JOIN table2 t2 on t1.pk = t2.fk
 JOIN table3 t3 on t2.pk = t3.fk
 WHERE t3.Description in ('Status', 'Material', 'Feet')) as SourceTable
PIVOT(MIN(Value) For Description in ([Status], [Material], [Feet])) as PivotTable
WHERE [Status] = 'Abandoned'
```

The problem I run into is using MIN will result in the following return

```
t1.PK  | t1.Col | t3.Status  | t3.Material | t3.Feet
----------------------------------------------------
123    |  Data  | Abandoned  |  Plastic    |  5
```

And using `MAX` returns nothing because I am trying to limit the Status to "Abandoned".

Is there a better way to do this? I think I understand why it's returning these values, I am just unsure of how to correct.

Comment: Your results seem to depend on the ordering of the rows -- what ties those three rows together?

Comment: I didn't want to put too many details but in doing so may have made a poor abstraction. The rows are tied together through form submissions. The data structure is table1 is the master record, table2 records the form submission event and table3 contains the actual form data. There can be multiple forms with the exact same structure tied to one master record, each with different values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.PK, t1.Col,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t3.Description = 'Status' THEN t3.Value END) as status,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t3.Description = 'Material' THEN t3.Value END) as material,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t3.Description = 'Feet' THEN t3.Value END) as feet
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2 
     ON t1.pk = t2.fk JOIN
     table3 t3 
     ON t2.pk = t3.fk
WHERE t3.Description in ('Status', 'Material', 'Feet')
GROUP BY t1.PK, t1.Col, t3.PK
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN t3.Description = 'Status' THEN t3.Value END) = 'Abandoned';
```

Comment: Thanks, I was going to give this a shot but had a moment of clarity that I was missing a limiter in the source table. Appreciate the input, if I get a few moments I'll try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was add a condition in the source table to limit the table3 FK's:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT t1.PK, t1.Col, t3.Description, t3.Value
 FROM table1 t1 
 JOIN table2 t2 on t1.pk = t2.fk
 JOIN table3 t3 on t2.pk = t3.fk
 WHERE t3.Description in ('Status', 'Material', 'Feet')
 AND t3.FK in (SELECT FK
               FROM table3
               WHERE Value = 'Abandoned')) as SourceTable
PIVOT(MIN(Value) For Description in ([Status], [Material], [Feet])) as PivotTable
WHERE [Status] = 'Abandoned'
```